# Proper way to unlockAccount

Tags: security, accounts

I'm running a private blockchain instance for personal development and I'm trying to understand what is the proper way to use `personal.unlockAccount()` to prevent a security risk.

I understand the usage of the function,

```
personal.unlockAccount(addr, password, duration)
```

I know that if I don't put a duration, the account remains unlocked for the default time (*which appears to be 300 seconds*).  With hacks and security risks, should I stick to `personal.unlockAccount(addr, password, 0.1)` or something of that nature?  Or is it unimportant that the account is unlocked (contrary to what I've been reading online regarding security risks / hacking vulnerabilities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sendRawTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction) to send signed transaction from the front end to the `geth` client so that you are not exposing the password to the network.

Example

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var privateKey = new Buffer('e331b6d69882b4cb4ea581d88e0b604039a3de5967688d3dcffdd2270c0fd109', 'hex')

var rawTx = {
  nonce: '0x00',
  gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000', 
  gasLimit: '0x2710',
  to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 
  value: '0x00', 
  data: '0x7f7465737432000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600057'
}

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(privateKey);

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

//console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'));
//0xf889808609184e72a00082271094000000000000000000000000000000000000000080a47f74657374320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000571ca08a8bbf888cfa37bbf0bb965423625641fc956967b81d12e23709cead01446075a01ce999b56a8a88504be365442ea61239198e23d1fce7d00fcfc5cd3b44b7215f

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
  if (!err)
    console.log(hash); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead79fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2c2eb7b11a91385"
});
```

Comment: Is this what's commonly done, or do people expose passwords to the network?

Comment: Exposing password to network is obviously risky. This is a good alternative, or you can disable web3 and make your own interface to interact with geth ipc from server side only.